# Can web app for ios run as smoothly as native?

Tags: ios, html, sencha-touch

Is there a framework that will allow to create web apps for iOS that will run as smoothly as native app?

I've checked demos of Sencha Touch http://www.sencha.com/products/touch on my iPad there's visible delay for touch events and for how precisely they are recognized. The feeling isn't the same as for native apps.

Is there other frameworks or technics that will allow to provide same experience as native apps?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your app. If your app is a hard-core heavy-duty 3D game, then no. If your app is primarily displaying static content ... like a web page or collection of photos, you might get close enough.

Comment: Even though you certainly are correct with this answer, I think you are describing extremes that are not matching too many apps. From my experience, you will already get a laggy user-experience as soon as you try to create smooth transition animations within a bread and butter app or have any user-interactions that are more than just a tap on a button (e.g. dragging).

Comment: Without a more specific scenario being stated in the question, we're all guessing at the scenario's needs. FWIW, using CSS3 transitions (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) can result in very smooth animations with very little markup. And there are plenty of pure-HTML/JS dragging employed by any number of sites and web-apps (e.g. AgileZen.com, PivotalTracker.com)

Answer (score 2):

Think about what experience you want to achieve first. If you want a cross platform application and you want to avoid the stores (App Store, Google Play, BB App World), then by all means, consider a web app.

Other things to consider, how much data do you estimate the user will need store locally (HTML apps are more limited in this respect); how much functionality is lost when there is no network connection, and does this loss of functionality make the app unusable.

Like the answer by @RichardTurner, if you need the kind of performance you find in the higher end games (Infinity Blade or Modern Combat 3), then native is the way to go.

Figure what you want, then you will have better idea of what technology to use.

Answer (score 1):

NO. Native apps will perform better every single time over web apps. If you want a smooth experience, go native. Also consider that some people have older model iOS devices and performance will be even more difficult to achieve on those devices in web apps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to consider with a Sencha app vs a native application.

1. You were browsing a Sencha Touch application online and chances are it wasn't a "packaged" version so you would have to download each source file individually.
2. With Sencha, you can utilize Sencha CMD to package an application which essentially builds a single minified js file containing only the required components from the Sencha library and your application (smaller DOM). You can also look into a production version which takes advantage of appcache. You'll see some performance increases here.
3. A packaged native Touch application will contain the actual JS, CSS, etc. files as part of the applications source, so their is no downloading from external resources.
4. You have to consider that any HTML5 application is going to have a ~300ms touch delay, more on that here: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away